# How to set up ldap pagination in TeamCity

Tags: ldap, teamcity

I am using LDAP login and synchronization in teamcity, but recently we have tipped over the sizeLimit in number of users, which has broken synchronization. I cannot limit the users being looked at any further. Is it possible to enable pagination in the ldap group synchronization?